# Real time + High frequency ADC data reading with Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, python-3, analog-to-digital, real-time, signal

I need to acquire a signal at a minimum sample rate of 10 kHz and processing it real-time using a Python code. Since Raspberry Pi only reads digital signals I get an ADC (High Precision AD/DA Board from Waveshare, with ADS1256 8 CHANNELS 24 BITS, SPI protocol). I'm using the source code provided by Waveshare in order to read channels' value.
How can I process ADC data at high sample rate in real-time? It seems that acquisition is interrupted when Raspberry is doing another task such as writing the values in a text file and the sampling frequency is not constant. I've read about buffers but my ADC does not implement these. Can I use threading and queues?

Comment: In addition to the Answer by joan DON'T use Python - which due to GIL only allows one task to run at a time - no matter how many cores you have. On a Pi4 with 4 CPU you can potentially run many tasks, but SPI will only read one channel at a time unless you use multiple SPI interfaces.

Comment: So, even if I implement multiprocessing on Python and save a number of readings to a list and then I pass that block to Pi in another thread with a set delay I cannot process that signal. Is It true?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing My experience has not indicated much (if any) gain, but if the tasks are truly independent it may work. I usually find it easier to use c for logging and use Python for the tasks it excels in. Even in the 1970s many of my tasks used a combination of FORTRAN (for array processing) and COBOL for input and output.

Comment: And what about processing a slow signal ( max 100Hz sampling rate)? Raspberry can take samples ~real time?

Answer (score 3):

Linux is not a real-time operating system.

You will not be able to achieve consistent sampling times using the standard Linux environment.

I have used DMA bit banging to get accurately timed SPI samples.

> By using bit-banging it is possible to get 12 bit ADC samples from one
> or more MCP3202s simultaneously. Rates of 25ksps per ADC can be
> achieved. Conventional SPI only allows one device to talk at a time.
> By using bit-banging you can share one CLK, MOSI, and SS (slave
> select) lines between many ADCs but give each its own MISO.
>
> An advantage of bit-banging is that you have tight control of when the
> samples are taken, in the case given every 40 μs, not as and when the
> SPI driver gets around to it.
>
> To bit-bang a chain of DMA blocks is used to switch the CLK, MOSI, and
> SS lines on/off according to the SPI requirements. The DMA blocks also
> contain gpio reads to capture the data transmitted by the ADC MISO
> lines. All gpios are read simultaneously (that's the way the Broadcom
> SOC works) so as many ADCs can be read as can be connected. In my
> experiment I used 2 ADCs as that is all I have.
>
> The waveforms are constructed by a modified version of the pigpio
> library. Each waveform is made up of a series of pulses which define
> its characteristics. Multiple waveforms are generated so that samples
> can be held in a cyclic buffer in memory (giving enough time to
> extract the readings). The waveform to capture one sample is given
> below.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=71089

Also see http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#C_rawMCP3202_c

Comment: And what if I need only 1 second of signal sampled at 10 kHz? Can I only save this record in a variable and process it as soon as I reach the number of samples required? Or Raspberry isn't able at all to save a record at such sampling rate?

Comment: You are asking if the Raspberry Pi is capable of storing 30 thousand bytes.  Yes, it is.